# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException When using Array of String

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Im having a problem on how can i get the string of array it gives me this error:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Error Detail:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.max.common.CampaignSyncEntity.getSyncAdKeywords(CampaignSyncEntity.java:249)
com.max.adwords.testsync.AWSyncTest.runSyncTest(AWSyncTest.java:21)
com.max.web.controller.CampaignSync.uploadMultipleFileHandler(CampaignSync.java:25)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

It seems that when getting an Null array of string this error occur.

This is the code on getting the null array:

```
public class AWSyncTest {
static CampaignSyncEntity syncEntity = new CampaignSyncEntity();
public void runSyncTest() {

    System.out.println("CAMPAIGN NAME: "+syncEntity.getSyncCampaignName());
    System.out.println("CAMPAIGN ID: "+syncEntity.getSyncCampaignId());
    System.out.println("AD GROUP NAME: "+syncEntity.getSyncAdGroupName());
    System.out.println("AD GROUP ID: "+syncEntity.getSyncAdGroupId());
    System.out.println("AD STATUS: "+syncEntity.getSyncAdStatus());
    System.out.println("TEXT AD TYPE: "+syncEntity.getSyncTextAdType());
    System.out.println("TEXT HEADLINE: "+syncEntity.getSyncTextHeadline());
    System.out.println("TEXT DESCRIPTION 1: "+syncEntity.getSyncTextDesc1());
    System.out.println("TEXT DESCRIPTION 2: "+syncEntity.getSyncTextDesc2());
    System.out.println("TEXT DISPLAY URL: "+syncEntity.getSyncTextDisplayURL());
    System.out.println("TEXT FINAL URL: "+syncEntity.getSyncTextFinalURL());
    System.out.println("KEYWORDS: "+Arrays.toString(syncEntity.getSyncAdKeywords()));
    System.out.println("NEGATIVE KEYWORD: "+syncEntity.getSyncAdNegativeKeywords());
    System.out.println("MATCH TYPE: "+syncEntity.getSyncAdMatchType());
    System.out.println("AD CRITERIA TYPE: "+syncEntity.getSyncAdCriteriaType());
    System.out.println("LOCATION: "+syncEntity.getSyncLocation());
    System.out.println("LOCATION ID: "+syncEntity.getSyncLocationId());

}
```

}

Hope you guys can help me about my problem, thanks in advance

Comment: What **exact** code is located in `CampaignSyncEntity` class, line 249?

Comment: From stack trace its clear the exception is at CampaignSyncEntity.java line 249. Please post that code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this line...

```
System.out.println("KEYWORDS: "+Arrays.toString(syncEntity.getSyncAdKeywords()));
```

I mean what is returned by `syncEntity.getSyncAdKeywords()`.

If its returning `null` problem is lying there..

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your code is trying to do something with a member/variable that hasn't been initialized - it's null. As you can see in the backtrace, the error occurs in `CampaignSyncEntity.java:249`.

When you jump to the line, most probably you will see some kind of action on a member/variable (i.e. something trying to access a member of the unitialized object) and when you go to `CampaignSyncEntity()` constructor's definition (which you used in the example code), the member that eventually is used in `CampaignSyncEntity.java:249` won't have anything assigned as well as in the place where the member is declared. If there is a variable used in `CampaignSyncEntity.java:249`, you should check where it is declared and what happens with it during the program flow. Probably it is returned by some function which can alse return a `Null` and that is in this case.

---

In such situations it is really helpful to use Java Debugger. Most IDEs have built-in debug GUI which makes it nice and smooth to use. Here's an example for Eclipse: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html . Especially look at **Watchpoint** feature - it allows you to track a field access/modification.